# apt-get fails with: "Unable to fetch..."

Tags: 14.04, apt

When I run apt-get, I get:

```
 ...
 W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  503  Service Unavailable
 ...
```

When I try "Select Best Server" in "software and updates", I get the message:

```
 "No suitable Download Server Was found. Please check your internet connection"
```

I can navigate the www, connect through ssh, etc.

What can be the issue?

(I am running trusty)

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried another mirror? If it works, 'what can be the issue' becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

apt-get was configured to use a proxy, by using a file  apt.conf

That proxy is no longer in use, so apt was not being able to use it.

The www worked, since it had its own proxy configuration (no proxy), through Network-> Network proxy